# Opening a file in C

Tags: c, linux, fopen

I looked at many examples before I wrote this, and I know many languages and clearly understand the syntax and what is going on in the code I listed below, however, when I compile my program for example:

`gcc -o /sbin/"name" readfile.c`

I get the following error:

[image]

This makes no since to me since my code clearly includes `#include <stdio.h>` which defines the `FILE` as referenced here ---- [stdio.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/stdio.h.html).

//PROGRAM (readfile.c)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("dummy.txt","w");
    fprintf(fp, "testing...\n");
    fclose(fp);
}
```

//FILE (dummy.txt) *is in the same directory

```
Hello World
```

Comment: Missing semicolon after `FILE *fp`.

Comment: @FatalError I'm sorry I'll update the answer but I have that in my code.

Comment: Please only post *actual code* - copy and paste from the original, don't type up an approximation - otherwise it just causes confusion and wastes time.

Comment: Yea yea sorry, it's good now.

Comment: No it's not - you still have `fprint` instead of `fprintf` - please *copy and paste*, don't just type an approximation of the code.

Comment: Use -Wall -Werror when you compile - perhaps it'll find something else wrong.  Also, I think you're using LLVM with the gcc wrapper, so a search for problems there may yield more useful results.

Comment: Damn yea I change `fprint`... the reason I didn't copy and paste in the first place was because I have VIM showing line numbers. I'll try using `-Wall`  and `-Werror`.

Comment: Maybe you have a BOM and your compiler can't handle it? (But then, I'd expect other errors)

Comment: @JordanDavis In VIM `:set nonumber`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. yea I know how to change the VIM config...

Comment: @ikegami yea i'll `cat` it next time

Comment: @JordanDavis But you prefer to retype the code here? Interesting.. Anyway, I can't reproduce your error.

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes yes I type very fast lol (not good sometimes)... lets get back to the question code is good now.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code as it appears now.  It compiles OK on my system.

Comment: Looking at this code (after the many typo corrections), the only cause would be that you have a damaged stdio.h in your toolset. Note that where the file to open is or what it contains are both irrelevant here since this is a compile time issue, not run time.

Comment: @JordanDavis  Cant get what exactly it is .  Seems you damaged file.

Comment: Can you just `printf` something?

Comment: I might suggest that perhaps, if you're compiling as the superuser directly into /sbin, then the chances are nonzero that you've opened and inadvertently edited stdio.h in a vim session that's running as root too?

Comment: @mah yea I must off damaged it... weird since this a brand new linux server I just fired up on AWS...

Comment: I'm create a new <stdio.h> file and copy it over see if that changes anything... It's got to be that, since none of you guys are getting that error and the code is working fine.

Comment: Yea my <stdio.h> file was damaged, works good now. Thank you everyone for you help.

Comment: @JordanDavis Please never every compile stuff as root. That's a really bad idea as the compiler is a large program full of bugs. You don't want to run it as root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a few minor mistakes

```
 FILE *fp                     // semi-colon required
 fprint(fp, "testing...\n";   // Its fprintf and missing ')'
 flcose(fp);                 // fclose  is function
```

Function is `fprintf` not `fprint`  also `fclose` not `flcose`.

Note - You should check return of `fopen`

Comment: I'm sorry I murdered the code when I copied it over, but I have both those edits and still outputting the error.

Comment: @JordanDavis  Then please post the excat code having error.

Comment: I just updated it and looked it over

Comment: @Jordan -  If you _correct your code in the original post, or do not represent your actual code in the first place_, it adds confusion.  Don't do that